# How to export Blender models as STL so that they can be printed on a 3D printer

Tags: export, 3d-printing

My first experiments exporting a model from Blender resulted in an incomplete looking model when used in Repetier-Host which I use for 3D printing. The model looks OK when imported, but after slicing, many parts seem to be missing, and the scale and positioning seem to be off. An stl file produced with Sketchup can be sliced and printed without issues.

Comment: Have you come across [this add-on](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/PrintToolbox) yet?

Comment: Hadn't seen it yet, I'll give it a try right away. Thanks!

Comment: Is it an additive printer? what material are you printing with? Sometimes the more flexy ones (ABU i think) can cave if you're printing hollow.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? What add-ons do you have activated (for example, 3d print toolbox)? Exactly how are you preparing your mesh for printing (a step by step description would be very helpful.)? Posting a Blend file would be useful.

Comment: @brasshat: Blender 2.72b. I activated the 3D printing tools as per ajwood's suggestion. It indicates a lot of problems with my model. I will try to fix these first before I get back to this page with further questions. Right now I don't have time. Thanks though!

Comment: @VinceScalia: I never got as far as printing the Blender  model yet. My printer is a Felixprinter 3.0 and I use PLA as a material.

Comment: I created a better model through extrusion instead of spinning a profile as I had done earlier. The new model was ok according to 3D print tools, and it printed fine.